# how to restore variables in fully_connected function

Tags: tensorflow, restore, checkpoint

In my training file(train.py), I write:

```
def deep_part(self):
    with tf.variable_scope("deep-part"):                                              
        y_deep = tf.reshape(self.embeddings, shape=[-1, self.field_size * self.factor_size]) # None * (F*K)
        # self.deep_layers = 2
        for i in range(0,len(self.deep_layers)):
            y_deep = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(y_deep, self.deep_layers[i], \ 
            activation_fn=self.deep_layers_activation, scope = 'fc%d' % i)
        return y_deep
```

now in predict file(predict.py), I restore the checkpoint, but I dont know how to reload the "deep-part" network's weights and biases.Because I think the "fully_conncted" function might hide the weights and biases.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a lengthy [explanation here](http://patwie.com/tutorials/tensorflow-introduction.html). A short summary:

By `saver.save(sess, '/tmp/my_model')` Tensorflow produces multiple files:

```
checkpoint
my_model.data-00000-of-00001
my_model.index
my_model.meta
```

The checkpoint file `checkpoint` is just a pointer to the latest version of our model-weights and it is simply a plain text file containing

```
$ !cat /tmp/model/checkpoint
model_checkpoint_path: "/tmp/my_model"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/tmp/my_model"
```

The others are binary files containing the graph (*.meta) and weights (*.data*).

You can help yourself by running

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(9 * 1).reshape(1, 9).astype(np.float32)

plhdr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 9], name='input')
print plhdr.name

activation = tf.layers.dense(plhdr, 10, name='fc')
print activation.name

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    expected = sess.run(activation, {plhdr: data})
    print expected

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    saver.save(sess, '/tmp/my_model')


tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # load the computation graph (the fully connected + placeholder)
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/my_model.meta')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    plhdr = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    activation = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('fc/BiasAdd:0')
    actual = sess.run(activation, {plhdr: data})
    assert np.allclose(actual, expected) is False

    # now load the weights
    loader = loader.restore(sess, '/tmp/my_model')
    actual = sess.run(activation, {plhdr: data})
    assert np.allclose(actual, expected) is True
```

Comment: I update my question, could you review it again? It's a puzzle to me how can I restore the weights and baises of the deep-part network. The fully_connected function just only statement the scope.